# System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0., Culture=nuetral failed CRM 2011

Tags: json, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to deserialize a json string in CRM 2011.  The JSON string is arbitrary and not always the same fields (keys) will be returned.  I am trying to use a `system.runtime.serialization.json datacontractjsonserialzer` method. I found the following code in another post that I have modified for my need:

```
namespace test
{
[Serializable]
public class stringObjectDictionary : ISafeSerializationData
{
public static Dictonary<string, object> dict;

public stringObjectDictionary()
{ dict = new Dictionary<string, object>(); }

protected stringObjectDictionary(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
foreach (Serialization entry in info)
{ dict.Add(key, dict[key]); }
}

void ISafeSerializationData.CompleteDeserialization(object obj)
{
Dictionary<string, object> _dict = obj as Dictionary<string, object>;
foreach (string key in dict.Keys)
{ _dict.Add(key, dict[key] }
}
```

I am calling the above here:

```
test.stringObjectDictionary[] dummyArray = { new test.stringObjectDictionary() };
DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(dummyArray.GetType());
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JSONString));
test.stringObjectDictionary[] dictArray =       (test.stringObjectDictionary[]).js.ReadObject(stream);
```

I am using the following for my test JSON:

```
 string testJSON = @"[{""ID"":34,""crmID"":""df4a2ab8-f1ad-e311-abb3-00155d02ea01""}, {""ID"":35,""crmID"":""df4a2ab8-f1ad-e311-abb3-0015d042fg94""}];
```

When I build and deploy and test the workflow I receive the security error.  This is deployed in the sandbox environment and needs to work in CRM online.  Is it possible to allow the class `stringObjectDictionary` to be fully trusted code so it can access the `system.security` namespace?

Comment: Please clarify which line is throwing the exception. In your test environment connect to **ALL** the Sanbox services to get VS to show you the specific line number.  No, it is not possible to make `stringObjectDictionary` into fully trusted code and run it in CRM Online - it is running in an AppDomain generated by the Sanbox service which has security restrictions placed on it.